# Elevated Button themedata border - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-theme

How can I implement sideBorder to elevatedButton through themedata.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9QQU.png)

```
 elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
    style: ButtonStyle(side: MaterialStateProperty<BorderSide>//Stuck here),
  ),
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To use Theme Data border in Elevated Button, you have use styleFrom method

```
elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2.5)) )
```

for more info [styleFrom](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton/styleFrom.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Could you add some commentary to this answer? What are you providing here that existing answers do not provide?